# How to check if a question has already been asked within a method in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, static-members

For one of my coding assignments, we are supposed to make a magic 8-ball program. One of the tasks we have to do is to make an instance variable called "userQuestions" that stores all of the questions asked in an ArrayList. We have a method called "ask" that should be updated to see if the user has already asked that question. If the question has already been asked, it should say "You already asked that question." But if it's a new question, then it will add the question to userQuestions ArrayList and generate a random response. I've been stuck for awhile now and I had some code earlier that made a loop that went through each element of userQuestions to see if it matched the question inputted, but it didn't work. We're supposed to loop through the list and compare the question to each question in the list, but I'm stuck on it. Also, I apologize if I formatted this question incorrectly or did this wrong. This is my first time uploading a question onto here. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
package task1;
import java.util.*;

public class Magic8Ball {
    private ArrayList<String> possibleResponses = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> userQuestions = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> actualResponses = new ArrayList<String>();
    Random num = new Random();
    
    public Magic8Ball() {
        possibleResponses.add("Outlook good");
        possibleResponses.add("My sources say no");
        possibleResponses.add("Reply hazy, try again");
    }

    public String ask( String question ) {
        userQuestions.add(question);
        return possibleResponses.get(num.nextInt(3));
    }


}
```

Here is the other class' code:

```
package task1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Magic8BallTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String question, reply;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Magic8Ball ball = new Magic8Ball();
        System.out.println("Ask the 8Ball a question (q to quit):");
        question = in.nextLine();
        while(!question.equals("q"))  {
            reply = ball.ask(question);
            System.out.println(reply);
            System.out.println("Ask the 8Ball a question (q to quit):");
            question = in.nextLine();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: See the [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method, e..g, `if (userQuestions.contains(question)) { return ... }`

Comment: Also, if the assignment allows it, consider using `Set<String>`.  Check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashset-arraylist-contains-performance) out.  The small data set from your question doesn't really matter which class is used, but may be useful for future projects.

Comment: You've been asked to use a list, so you should, but for future reference a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) is a better data structure to use here. Also, when you declare a list, you can use the "diamond" syntax, and you should code to the interface, not the implementation. So declare your lists like: `private List<String> userQuestions = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: The question is a duplicate